# Getting asylum due to health reasons?

Tags: visa, asylum

Let me introduce myself. I'm a Russian citizen, but don't live there last years due to health reasons (I've got chronic bronchitis and asthma, and some unidentified immune problems). That's why I currently live in tropical countries, where I can get visas for some time.

I have a decent income from freelance programming, so I don't have any money problems. But visas are a big problem, especially considering what the Russian government is doing last time, there are high chances my visa application will be rejected. I can't live in Russia, because climate there damages my health too much. Last time I've been there I had bronchitis in acute phase for almost all winter and spring and lost 15 kilograms of body weight.

So… is there any chance to get asylum due to health reasons, somewhere where it's not too cold?

Comment: Rules may heavily depend on the country in question.  En Masse the answer is no.

Comment: @Karlson, bad luck for me, then.

Comment: What countries have you thought of? Since you're a programmer, it may be easier for you just to get a job and work permit. There could be also residence options like Turkey for example.

Comment: @Elchin, getting full time job isn't really easy, candidates without work permit usually aren't even considered. Very few companies are willing to hassle with work permit bureaucracy. I'm thinking about getting residence without right to work in the country (assuming it doesn't forbid remote work).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No**, there is no chance.  "Asylum" is shorthand for [*political* asylum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_of_asylum): it means another state offering you shelter when you are being persecuted due to "race, caste, nationality, religion, political opinions".  None of these apply to you, since your problem is with the climate, not the Russian government.

If moving to sunny Crimea is not an option, you would probably be better off looking for a warm country that will grant you a business or other long-term stay visa.  Cambodia has long been [famously easy](http://www.movetocambodia.com/planning-your-move-to-cambodia/cambodia-visas/), with one-year visas handed to anybody with a pulse (optional) and a few hundred dollars (mandatory), though they're apparently tightening things up a bit.  If you're willing and able to invest a few hundred thousand dollars in property, almost any country in South-East Asia will happily give you a visa.

Comment: "sunny Crimea" Way to make fun of it...

Comment: Crimea was one of the warmest places in the ex-Soviet Union and was a popular holiday destination for that reason.  If the OP is looking for a warm place he can get to without a visa, it's an entirely viable option. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimea#Climate

Comment: "sunny Crimea", no trolling please... it's a (quite) popular summer vacation place, despite having high prices and poor service. But winters are nasty, especially for a person with my problems. And I hate what the Russian government is doing there. And of course I don't have hundreds thousands of dollars, I'm not a freaking oil oligarch.

Comment: talking about asylum for political opinions - I've been supporting opposition to the government, but I guess the government's pressure isn't bad enough (yet?) to make this option viable.

Comment: PS I've been to Cambodia and didn't like it at all. The place is completely devastated. Another possible option is Mexico - hopefully it will work out better.